# (Python) ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, unix, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I'm having an issue with python not liking values with decimals. I believe that it wants the numbers in whole number format, not decimal...

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotpoints.py", line 29, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt('/home/weather/data/mos/full_highs_00z', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

**Code:**

```
data = np.loadtxt('/home/weather/data/mos/full_highs_00z', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-85:64:dx, 34:49:dx]

grid_z = griddata((data[:,1],data[:,0]), data[:,2], (grid_x,grid_y), method='cubic')
```

**Contents of full_highs_00z:**

```
latitude,longitude,value
42.88355,-76.78116,81
37.1417,-79.0164,0
36.65408,-83.21783,90
41.00928,-74.73628,89.94
42.29133,-73.71033,0
43.77714,-71.75598,88
44.41944,-72.01944,86.24
```

Since the third column in full_highs_00z contains the values with decimals, I have a hunch that "data[:,2]" is the code that is having issues with the data being decimal and not whole numbers.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with your data, are you sure that is the complete `full_highs_00z` file?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that there were some fields that had missing data, so just used

```
sed -i '/,0/d' /home/weather/data/mos/full_highs_00z
```

to delete the lines that had zeros in them!